# overlay a picture on canvas temporary

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am working on a demo in html5 and this is what i want to do:

I already have a  element which act as a drawing board, and one person is drawing randomly on it.

now I want to :

- on top of the canvas, temporarily show(overlay) a small picture and some text message for a few seconds. then fade out.
- the overlay should not block the user from continue drawing.
- the overlayed picture should disappear clearly,  not overwrite the drawing bellow. or block the mouse action.

how can I do this?

very appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You do the painting by reading the mouse coordinates and if a mouse button is down, right? Then all you have to do is keep reading these values from the mouse.

If you are just listening for mouse events inside the canvas element I can see there will be a problem if you place any element above it. If so, you will have to switch to listening for mouse events on the complete document (`document.addEventListener('mousemove', ...)` etc).

Comment: is it possible to have to canvas overlaping on each other, then have the top layer being transparent, and also pass-on the mouse actions to the under layer?

Comment: Yes, you can treat the canvas element as any arbitrary html element. Ie you can change its css style propreties such as `top`, `left`, `opacity`, `z-index`, etc. Pass on mouse actions; you can listen for them globally (on the document level) and then invoke the appropriate functions that can affect the correct canvas.